# JavaScript TypeError only in IE 11

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

When loading a js e-form in IE getting an error 'loadForm: if GroupDocList>0: TypeError: Unable to get property 'length; of undefined or null reference

This only occurs in IE not Chrome or Edge.

This form was coded by someone else and I don't have much experience with JS

Update * Through debugging I was able to find that it is the CompList object that is undefined and causing this error. Wondering why this is being undefined at this point within IE but working within Chrome and Edge or at least not throwing the error.

`for (var i = 0; i < CompList.length; i++) {`

```
function CreatePopulateDataSet() {
        //*************************************************************************
        //Company/Division/SubCat/Plan dataset populate - BEGIN********************
        //*************************************************************************
        var g_CompanyList = {};
        var g_DivisionList = {};
        var g_SubCatList = {};

        try {
            if ($("#selCompanyList").find("option").length > 0) {
                try {
                    $("#selCompanyList option").each(function () {
                        var Comp = $(this).text().split("|")[0];
                        var Div = $(this).text().split("|")[1];
                        var SubCat = $(this).text().split("|")[2];
                        var Plant = $(this).text().split("|")[3];

                        var CompList = g_CompanyList[Comp];
                        var DivList = g_DivisionList[Comp + Div];
                        var SubList = g_SubCatList[Comp + Div + SubCat];

                        try {
                            if (hasCompanyAccess(Comp)) {
                                if (!CompList) { CompList = new Array(); }
                                if ($.inArray(Div, CompList) == -1) {
                                    CompList.push(Div);
                                    g_CompanyList[Comp] = CompList;
                                }

                                if (!DivList) { DivList = new Array(); }
                                if (SubCat != null) {
                                    if ($.inArray(SubCat, DivList) == -1) {
                                        DivList.push(SubCat);
                                        g_DivisionList[Comp + Div] = DivList;
                                    }
                                }
                                if (!SubList) { SubList = new Array(); }
                                if (Plant != null) {
                                    if ($.inArray(Plant, SubList) == -1) {
                                        SubList.push(Plant);
                                        g_SubCatList[Comp + Div + SubCat] = SubList;
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        catch (err) {
                            alert("Unable build global lists used to populate drop downs. " + err);
                        }
                    });
                }
                catch (err) {
                    alert(err);
                }

                $("#selPARCompany").html("<option value=''>Please Select...</option>");
                for (var Comp in g_CompanyList) {
                    $("#selPARCompany").append("<option value='" + Comp + "'>" + Comp + "</option>");
                }
                $("#selPARCompany").addClass("fullwidth");

                //Cascade Reload - BEGIN
                //Re-loads/populates the cascading data set if the form has been submitted.
                if ($("#OBPropertyItemNum").val()) {

                    //re-sets the Company drop down box on load of a submitted form.
                    var tempComp = $("#txtPARCompany").val();
                    $("#selPARCompany option").each(function () {
                        if ($(this).text().toUpperCase() == tempComp.toUpperCase()) {
                            $(this).attr("selected", "selected");
                        }
                    });
                    //Calls the CompanyTabOverride method to set access to the corrct tabs based on the saved value.
                    CompanyTabOverride(tempComp);

                    var CompList = g_CompanyList[$("#selPARCompany option:selected").text().toUpperCase()];
                    var tempDiv = $("#txtPARDivision").val();

                    //re-load and populate the Division drop down box
                    for (var i = 0; i < CompList.length; i++) {
                        if (i == 0)
                            $("#selPARDivision").html("<option value=''>Please Select...</option>");
                        if (CompList[i].toUpperCase() == tempDiv.toUpperCase()) {
                            $("#selPARDivision").append("<option selected=selected label='" + CompList[i] + "' value='" + CompList[i] + "'>" + tempComp + CompList[i] + "</option>");
                        } else {
                            $("#selPARDivision").append("<option label='" + CompList[i] + "' value='" + CompList[i] + "'>" + tempComp + CompList[i] + "</option>");
                        }
                    }
                    if ($("#selPARDivision option").length > 1) {
                        $("#selPARDivision").closest("td").show();
                        $("#selPARDivision").addClass("required");
                    } else {
                        $("#selPARDivision").closest("td").hide();
                        $("#selPARDivision").removeClass("required");
                        $("#selPARDivision").removeClass("requiredInput");
                    }

                    DivisionTabOverride(tempComp, tempDiv);

                    //re-load and populate the Sub Category drop down box
                    var tempSubCat = $("#txtPARSubCat").val();
                    var DivList = g_DivisionList[$("#selPARDivision option:selected").text().toUpperCase()];
                    var Div = $("#selPARDivision option:selected").html();
                    if (tempSubCat != "") {
                        for (var i = 0; i < DivList.length; i++) {
                            if (i == 0)
                                $("#selPARSubCat").html("<option  value=''>Please Select...</option>");

                            if (DivList[i].toUpperCase() == tempSubCat.toUpperCase()) {
                                $("#selPARSubCat").append("<option selected=selected label='" + DivList[i] + "' value='" + DivList[i] + "'>" + Div + DivList[i] + "</option>");
                            } else {
                                $("#selPARSubCat").append("<option  label='" + DivList[i] + "' value='" + DivList[i] + "'>" + Div + DivList[i] + "</option>");
                            }
                        }
                        if ($("#selPARSubCat option").length > 1) {
                            $("#selPARSubCat").closest("td").show();
                            $("#selPARSubCat").addClass("required");
                        } else {
                            $("#selPARSubCat").closest("td").hide();
                            $("#selPARSubCat").removeClass("required");
                            $("#selPARSubCat").removeClass("requiredInput");
                        }
                    }

                    //re-load and populate the Plant drop down box.
                    var tempPlant = $("#txtPARPlant").val();
                    var SubList = g_SubCatList[$("#selPARSubCat option:selected").text().toUpperCase()];
                    var SubCat = $("#selPARSubCat option:selected").html();
                    if (tempPlant != "") {
                        for (var i = 0; i < SubList.length; i++) {
                            if (i == 0)
                                $("#selPARPlant").html("<option value=''>Please Select...</option>");
                            if (SubList[i].toUpperCase() == tempPlant.toUpperCase()) {
                                $("#selPARPlant").append("<option selected=selected label='" + SubList[i] + "' value='" + SubList[i] + "'>" + SubCat + SubList[i] + "</option>");
                            } else {
                                $("#selPARPlant").append("<option label='" + SubList[i] + "' value='" + SubList[i] + "'>" + SubCat + SubList[i] + "</option>");
                            }
                        }
                        if ($("#selPARPlant option").length > 1) {
                            $("#selPARPlant").closest("td").show();
                            $("#selPARPlant").addClass("required");
                        } else {
                            $("#selPARPlant").closest("td").hide();
                            $("#selPARPlant").removeClass("required");
                            $("#selPARPlant").removeClass("requiredInput");
                        }
                    }
                }
                //Cascade Reload - END

                try {
                    $("#selPARCompany").bind("change", function () {
                        var Comp = $(this).val();

                        $("#selPARDivision").html("<option value=''>Please Select...</option>");
                        $("#txtPARDivision").val("");
                        $("#selPARSubCat").html("<option  value=''>Please Select...</option>");
                        $("#txtPARSubCat").val("");
                        $("#selPARPlant").html("<option value=''>Please Select...</option>");
                        $("#txtPARPlant").val("");

                        if ($(this)[0].selectedIndex > 0) {
                            var CompList = g_CompanyList[Comp];
                            for (var i = 0; i < CompList.length; i++) {
                                //$("#selPARDivision").append("<option value='" + Comp + CompList[i] + "'>" + CompList[i] + "</option>");
                                $("#selPARDivision").append("<option label='" + CompList[i] + "' value='" + CompList[i] + "'>" + Comp + CompList[i] + "</option>");
                            }
                        }
                        $("#selPARDivision").addClass("fullwidth");
                        $("#txtPARCompany").val($("#selPARCompany").val());

                        if ($("#selPARDivision option").length > 1) {
                            $("#selPARDivision").closest("td").show();
                            $("#selPARDivision").addClass("required");

                            $("#selPARSubCat").closest("td").hide();
                            $("#selPARSubCat").removeClass("required");
                            $("#selPARSubCat").removeClass("requiredInput");
                            $("#selPARPlant").closest("td").hide();
                            $("#selPARPlant").removeClass("required");
                            $("#selPARPlant").removeClass("requiredInput");
                        } else {
                            $("#selPARDivision").closest("td").hide();
                            $("#selPARDivision").removeClass("required");
                            $("#selPARDivision").removeClass("requiredInput");
                            $("#selPARSubCat").closest("td").hide();
                            $("#selPARSubCat").removeClass("required");
                            $("#selPARSubCat").removeClass("requiredInput");
                            $("#selPARPlant").closest("td").hide();
                            $("#selPARPlant").removeClass("required");
                            $("#selPARPlant").removeClass("requiredInput");
                        }
                        CompanyTabOverride(Comp);
                        IsEngineeringLevelRequired(Comp);
                        IsUniqPlanIDRequired(Comp, $('#selPARExpenditureinBusinessPlan').find(":selected").text());
                        //$('#selPARExpenditureinBusinessPlan').change();
                    });


                    $("#selPARDivision").bind("change", function () {
                        var Div = $("#" + $(this).attr("id") + " option:selected").html();

                        $("#selPARSubCat").html("<option  value=''>Please Select...</option>");
                        $("#txtPARSubCat").val("");
                        $("#selPARPlant").html("<option value=''>Please Select...</option>");
                        $("#txtPARPlant").val("");

                        if ($(this)[0].selectedIndex > 0) {
                            var DivList = g_DivisionList[Div];
                            if (DivList) {
                                for (var i = 0; i < DivList.length; i++) {
                                    //$("#selPARSubCat").append("<option value='" + Div + DivList[i] + "'>" + DivList[i] + "</option>");
                                    $("#selPARSubCat").append("<option  label='" + DivList[i] + "' value='" + DivList[i] + "'>" + Div + DivList[i] + "</option>");
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        $("#selPARSubCat").addClass("fullwidth");

                        $("#txtPARDivision").val($("#selPARDivision").val());

                        if ($("#selPARSubCat option").length > 1) {
                            $("#selPARSubCat").closest("td").show();
                            $("#selPARSubCat").addClass("required");

                            $("#selPARPlant").closest("td").hide();
                            $("#selPARPlant").removeClass("required");
                            $("#selPARPlant").removeClass("requiredInput");
                        } else {
                            $("#selPARSubCat").closest("td").hide();
                            $("#selPARSubCat").removeClass("required");
                            $("#selPARSubCat").removeClass("requiredInput");
                            $("#selPARPlant").closest("td").hide();
                            $("#selPARPlant").removeClass("required");
                            $("#selPARPlant").removeClass("requiredInput");
                        }
                        DivisionTabOverride($("#selPARCompany").val(), $(this).val());
                    });

                    $("#selPARSubCat").bind("change", function () {
                        //var SubCat = $(this).val();
                        var SubCat = $("#" + $(this).attr("id") + " option:selected").html();

                        $("#selPARPlant").html("<option value=''>Please Select...</option>");
                        $("#txtPARPlant").val("");

                        if ($(this)[0].selectedIndex > 0) {
                            var SubList = g_SubCatList[SubCat];
                            if (SubList) {
                                for (var i = 0; i < SubList.length; i++) {
                                    //$("#selPARPlant").append("<option value='" + SubCat + SubList[i] + "'>" + SubList[i] + "</option>");
                                    $("#selPARPlant").append("<option label='" + SubList[i] + "' value='" + SubList[i] + "'>" + SubCat + SubList[i] + "</option>");
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        $("#selPARPlant").addClass("fullwidth");

                        $("#txtPARSubCat").val($("#selPARSubCat").val());

                        if ($("#selPARPlant option").length > 1) {
                            $("#selPARPlant").closest("td").show();
                            $("#selPARPlant").addClass("required");
                        } else {
                            $("#selPARPlant").closest("td").hide();
                            $("#selPARPlant").removeClass("required");
                            $("#selPARPlant").removeClass("requiredInput");
                        }
                    });

                    $("#selPARPlant").bind("change", function () {
                        $("#txtPARPlant").val($("#selPARPlant").val());
                    });

                }
                catch (err) {
                    alert("loadForm: if GroupDocList>0: bind Group Change:" + err);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (err) {
            alert("loadForm: if GroupDocList>0: " + err);
        }
```

Comment: *"Any help of what to look into would be appreciated!"* `TypeError: Unable to get property 'length; of undefined or null reference` somewhere in that `try` block, JS is trying to access the `length` of something that isn't there (`null` or `undefined`). Since your snippet does not contain the part accessing the `length`, I can't be any more specific about why or what is wrong

Comment: Can we see the `try` before the `catch`?

Comment: If the error is only in IE, it may be using some function not supported by that browser, like `array.includes`. Post the code that it's in the `try` block.

Comment: Edited with the code from the try block

Comment: Where ever you see `.length` in the `try` block you can `console.log` that item *before* checking the length. If any of those are `undefined` or `null` you'll know which is causing the problem.

Comment: I found around 4 occurrences of .length in your code. You can try to debug your code to check which .length is throwing an error from 4 of them. Then you can try to  try to fix it.

Comment: `$("#" + $(this).attr("id") + " option:selected")` === `$(this).find("option:selected")`

Comment: this entire code does not matter, first it's inside another `try/catch` block, so the error would be catched there not in where you see the error, second these occurances of `length` are inside callback functions, errors in that part of your code would not be catched by this `try/catch` anyway. Where does the relevant `try`-block start? what code is missing there?

Comment: Edited with entire block where error is coming from and where I believe I have debugged to the issue

Comment: As per your debugging, CompList is undefined. You can try to check this line. var CompList = g_CompanyList[$("#selPARCompany option:selected").text().toUpperCase()]; Try to remove methods one by one from it to check why it is undefined. Also try to assign static value for testing purpose to check whether it solves this error. It can help to verify it.